# Code won't write a file when using Python 3

Tags: python, powershell, python-3.x

I am using Notepad++ as an editor and I am running Python 3 from Notepad.
This is the code:

```
import sys

def write():
    print ("Creating new file")
    name = 'NewFile.txt'
    file = open(name,'w')
    file.close()
write()
```

The problem is not the code itself, I think. When I run the code from Windows PowerShell like this: `python code.py`, it works fine and creates the file, but this is creating the file using Python 2.7. I need to use Python 3.

When I run Python 3 from Notepad++ the file won't be created.

I tried running Python 2.7 from Notepad++ but it just doesn't work. I run it like this:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

or with Python 3 I run it like this:

```
C:\Python35\python.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" .
```

I also run Notepad++ as administrator.

I think I could solve this by running Python 3 alongside Python 2 in PowerShell, but I don't know how and the answers to these questions do not work for me:

- [How do I add Python 3.3 to Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364207/how-do-i-add-python-3-3-to-powershell)
- [I'm trying to use python in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813435/im-trying-to-use-python-in-powershell)

I am open to changing my editor (Notepad++) or any solutions really.

So, how can I make Notepad++ create a new file?  Or How can I make Python 3 run in PowerShell? Or Which editor could I use to fix this? Or maybe my code is just wrong.

**Edit:** When I say it doesn't work I mean that the file will not be created even tough my code runs (no error msg).

*To be clear, what you're describing seems to be: a) when you run your file manually from the command prompt, it gives the expected results; b) when you run it instead through Notepad++, you don't see any evidence that it runs at all. Is that right?.*

Yes, that's right. I'm also not sure what is the interactive interpreter.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Does your program throw an error? Does a kitten dance across your screen? Be specific.

Comment: To be clear, what you're describing seems to be: a) when you run your file manually from the command prompt, it gives the expected results; b) when you run it instead through Notepad++, you don't see any evidence that it runs at all. Is that right?

Comment: In particular, since you're already running Python with `-i`, does the interactive interpreter appear when you run it from notepad++?

Comment: What result do you get when you run both statements without `-i` from PowerShell? Your code works just fine for me in both Python 2.7 and 3.5.

Comment: When I run it without the -i it just dosn't create the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the file *is* being created, but not in the place where you expect it. You define the file without a path, so it's created in the current working directory. Check the program directory or the system directory for the file.

Specify output files with the full path to avoid this issue:

```
import sys

def write():
    print ("Creating new file")
    name = 'C:/path/to/NewFile.txt'
    file = open(name,'w')
    file.close()
write()
```

Comment: THIS IS IT. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the encoding of your input file.
When you open the file, put an encoding option to match your editor.